# Angular : How to bind href tag with json key?

Tags: html, angular

I have a json that contains a value something like this:

```
{test_link : www.test.com}
```

I want to fetch this value in a href tag in my html component, something like this:

```
<a href={{test_link}}> test </a>
```

But I am not able to achieve this. Getting error tag a is not closed.
Any leads on this?

Comment: Either `[href]={{test_link}}` or `href="{{test_link}}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="{{test_link}}"> test </a>
```

or

```
<a [href]="test_link"> test </a>
```